# Firebase Firestore Upload Methods Taking Far Longer Than Other Methods

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

So I created an app using Ionic and Firebase as my back-end. When the app is run in a web browser or on an iOS emulator, the response is very fast and the app works really well. On iOS however, uploading anything to Firebase takes forever. Note that downloading information from Firebase is fairly fast and simple. Uploading however poses an issue. The wifi I am testing this on is very fast. Does anyone know why this is happening?

The app was released recently and this has been an issue for a lot of my users and myself included!

UPDATE: So after more testing it appears that the issue is specifically with certain functions. These methods are .update() and .add()

Anytime I try to update a field in Firebase it takes forever. Anytime I try to add a document to a collection it also takes forever. Why is this occuring? Here's some code that takes forever to achieve:

```js
async createDMChat(otherUID: string, otherName: string) {
        let newDoc: DocumentReference = this.db.firestore.collection('dmchats').doc();
        let docId: string = newDoc.id;
        let chatsArray = this.dmChats.value;
        let timestamp = Date.now();
        chatsArray.push(docId);
        //Adds to your dm chat
        await this.db.collection('users').doc('dmchatinfo').collection('dmchatinfo').doc(this.dataService.uid.value).set({
            chatsArray: chatsArray
        });
        //Adds to other person DM chat
        //-------------------THIS IS THE PART THAT TAKES FOREVER-----------------------
        //The .update() method is the problem as well as .add() to a collection
        await this.db.collection('users').doc('dmchatinfo').collection('dmchatinfo').doc(otherUID).update({
            chatsArray: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(docId)
        });

        //Pull info on person's UID
        let otherUserInfo = await this.db.firestore.collection('users').doc('user').collection('user').doc(otherUID).get();

        let otherAvatar = otherUserInfo.data().avatar;

        //Sets message in database
        await newDoc.set({
            chatName: otherName + " & " + this.dataService.user.value.name,
            users: [otherUID, this.dataService.uid.value],
            lastPosted: timestamp,
            avatar1: this.dataService.avatarUrl.value,
            avatar2: otherAvatar,
            person1: otherName,
            person2: this.dataService.user.value.name
        });

        await newDoc.collection('messages').doc('init').set({
            init: 'init'
        });

        await this.dataService.storage.set(docId, timestamp);
    }
```

In the above code, the .update() is the method that takes forever. Also other functions with the .add() method adding documents to a collection takes forever.

Again THESE METHODS ARE FAST ON WEB BROWSERS AND EMULATORS. Just not in the mobile app.

===========================================================================

NEW UPDATE: So it appears that the problem is actually in waiting for the Promise to return. I rewrote all of the functions used to no longer use add() or update(), but rather used set() after making a new document with doc() to replace add(). I then used set({...},{merge: true}) to replace update().

This time around the changes to the server were instant, but the problem came when waiting for the methods to return a promise from the server. This is the part that is causing the lag now. Does anyone know why this is occurring? I could simply change my code to not wait for these promises to return, but I would like to keep await within my code without having this issue.

Comment: It's a bit hard to track the reason for your latency as it may vary depending on many factors. Are you using any proxy or firewalls in your network? Are you far from the location of your Firestore database? Also, does this happen in any mobile independently of their OS?

Comment: Hey I isolated the issue more so to determine the issue is waiting for promises to return from the server. How do I mitigate this issue?